# Error al insertar datos en tabla de MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Help me, al momento de insertar datos en la tabla producto me salta este:

Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 2

Tabla

```
 create table Producto(
idProducto int not null,
Nombre_Producto varchar(45) not null,
Precio_Producto float not null,
Marca_Producto varchar(45) not null,
Stock_Producto int null,
rucSucursal_fk int (10) not null,
rucProveedor_fk int (13) not null,
idTipo_Producto_fk int not null,
 primary key (idProducto),
index (rucSucursal_fk),
index (rucProveedor_fk),
index (idTipo_Producto_fk),
constraint rucSucursal_fk foreign key (rucSucursal_fk) references Sucursal(rucSucursal),
constraint rucProveedor_fk foreign key (rucProveedor_fk) references Proveedor_Producto(rucProveedor),
constraint idTipo_Producto_fk foreign key (idTipo_Producto_fk) references Tipo_Producto (idTipo_Producto)
) engine = InnoDB;
```

INSERT

```
insert into producto (idProducto, Nombre_Producto, Precio_Producto, Marca_Producto, Stock_Producto, rucSucursal_fk, rucProveedor_fk, idTipo_Producto_fk)
                values (1,'Finalin',1,'Finalin',45,1,2,5),
                       (2,'Condones DUO',2.50,'Duo',56,1,3),
                       (3,'Nido',16.50,'Nido',72,1,2,7),
                       (4,'Colgate',1.50,'Colgate',23,4,1,2),
                       (5,'Viagra',15.00,'COMOPIEDRA',3,6),
                       (6,'Té Organico',4.60,'SHICURA',80,3,4,03),
                       (7,'Tamponones',1.00,'LINEA CMAMO',21,3,3,2),
                       (8,'Paracetamol',2.50,'FARMA',73,3,2,1),
                       (9,'Ibutefreno',2.50,'FARMA',20,2,2,1),
                       (10,'Purgante', 3.25,'SIETEREX',61,2,6,3);
```

Me sale ese error cada vez que intento insertar reviso la tabla y el insert pero sigue igual, no entiendo el error.

Comment: En la fila 2 falta un dato, solo has puesto 7 de 8. `(2,'Condones DUO',2.50,'Duo',56,1,3),`

Comment: gracias, ya me cuenta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisando detalladamente, me faltaba agregar datos dentro de la tabla, por ejemplo en la columna dos. Pero aun faltaban algunos detalles más dentro de la tabla para agregar. Es decir después de la marca del producto debería a ver cuatro columnas de números pero en algunas filas solo había 2 o 3, así que faltaban datos. Ya lo corregí y funciono.

```
insert into producto (idProducto, Nombre_Producto, Precio_Producto, Marca_Producto, Stock_Producto, rucSucursal_fk, rucProveedor_fk, idTipo_Producto_fk)
                values (1,'Finalin',1,'Finalin',45,1,2,5),
                       (2,'Condones DUO',2,'Duo',56,1,3,6),
                       (3,'Nido',16,'Nido',72,1,2,7),
                       (4,'Colgate',1,'Colgate',23,4,1,2),
                       (5,'Viagra',15,'COMOPIEDRA',20,3,3,6),
                       (6,'Té Organico',4,'SHICURA',80,3,4,3),
                       (7,'Tamponones',1,'LINEA CMAMO',21,3,3,2),
                       (8,'Paracetamol',2,'FARMA',73,3,2,1),
                       (9,'Ibutefreno',2,'FARMA',20,2,2,1),
                       (10,'Purgante', 3,'SIETEREX',61,2,6,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

El error "Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 2" indica que en `values ()` se ha introducido un número menor o mayor al de número de columnas que la tabla tiene. O también puede indicar que no has especificado las columnas en las que se deben insertar los datos.

Más información en [este enlace](https://tableplus.com/blog/2019/09/column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1.html)